# Best way to store "percentages" while programming?

Tags: maintainability

I have a financial application that deals with "percentages" quite frequently.  We are using "decimal" types to avoid rounding errors.  My question is:

If I have a quantity representing 76%, is it better to store it as `0.76` or `76`?

Furthermore, what are the advantages and/or disadvantages from a code maintainability point of view?  Are there conventions for this?

Comment: I think it depends on the language and/or platform. Unless you state what those are, it's going to be difficult to answer your question.

Comment: This question is more suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarkSeemann Here is some context: we are programming a web-application in python/django.  The web-application uses MySQL as a database.  That said, I don't see why this really depends much on the language or platform...

Comment: @Selcuk that does seem like a better place to post this, sorry :(

Is there a way to move it over?

Comment: @jdg Well, if you were programming in JavaScript, for example, IIRC, there's only a single numeric data type, so there would be no difference between `0.76` and `76`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann What do you mean there is no difference?  76 !== 0.76.  I guess as mentioned, I am not worried about rounding errors.  Its more of a conceptual question: does it make more "sense" to store numbers as a fraction or *100.  My guess is the former, as multiplying by 100 is really a display issue.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that there would be no difference from a memory usage perspective. `0.76` and `76` would take up the same about of bytes of memory... Obviously, I'm not implying that `0.76` === `76` :)

Comment: @MarkSeemann Oh yeah of course, btw sorry since I probably came of as a jerk with that comment.  But do you see the dilemma now?  Its a bigger picture type question; as Selcuk mentioned, I should have put it on the programmers site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If *percentage* is only a small part of the problem domain, I would probably stick with a primitive number.

*PerCent* literally means *per hundred*, and is a decimal number; e.g. `76 %` is *equal to* `0.76`. Thus, in the absence of [*units of measure* support in the programming language itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx), I would represent a percentage as a decimal number.

This also means that you don't need to perform special arithmetic in order to calculate with percentages, but you *will* need to multiply by 100 if you need to display the number in percent.

If *percentage* is a very central part of the problem domain, you should consider discarding [Primitive Obsession](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession) and instead introduce a proper [Value Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html).

Still, even if you introduce a `Percent` Value Object that contains conversions to and from primitive numbers, you're still stuck with potential programmer errors, because in itself, the number `0.9` could both mean `90 %` or `0.9 %` depending on how you choose to interpret it.

In the end, my best advice is to cover your code base with appropriate **unit tests**, so that you lock the conversion code down.